# can I typecast one subclass to other subclass object in C#

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance

I want to type cast a below:

```
Class A
{
}

Class B : A
{
}

Class C: A
{
}
Class D{
B b = new b();
C c = (C) b;
}
```

Please suggest how can I type cast class C to Class B

Comment: What makes you think you should be doing this?

Answer (score 5):

No, that's not possible since B is **not** a C, so this cast must fail. One workaround would be to implement a custom explicit conversion operator but otherwise there is no way - you can only cast to a more specific type (downcast) or to a base class (upcast) in the same inheritance tree.

Answer (score 2):

You can not.
What you can is cast B to A.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply impossible. You can't to such conversion.

In fact they have same base class, but they **aren't** same. For example, take a look at this.

`Triangle` is `Shape` and
`Rectangle` is `Shape`

But you can't convert `Triangle` to `Rectangle`, because they are different.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't.  If you want to copy properties from one class to another, you might consider [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. Classes C and B are not related in the class hierachy.

Comment: This is a poor analogy. Using this we could say the two sons are also each others mother.

Answer (score 1):

```
Animal
{
}

Giraffe : Animal
{
}

Shark : Animal
{
}
```

Your question is how do you turn a Giraffe into a Shark. Unfortunately, it can't be done.